# Maven war plugin copy arbitrary files

Tags: maven, maven-war-plugin

I apologize that this is surely basic maven/war plugin stuff, but I'm totally not a maven user. I just have to hack this one thing into a project that is maven based.

What I need to do is to copy an (essentially arbitrary) directory and files into the root of my war. I need them to appear as resources available via HTTP when the war deploys.

I cannot simply put them in the "right place" in the source tree. This is because the files in question are actually the source files of my project. I realize this is a bit odd, but this is a documentation project, and I need to show the source and the effect all in the same war.

So, in the general case, how would I configure the maven war plugin to copy a given directory, along with it's contents, to the root of my war? (BTW, I have tried to make sense of the documentation of this tool, but it seems to be predicated on so much understanding of maven that it feels like I'll never understand it without learning maven first, and I'm a bit too pressed for time to do that just now!)

Many TIA
Toby.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try:

1. use the [copy-resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) plugin. Use the plugin to copy your source files under `target` prior to when the war is packaged.
2. or, configure the [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) to include additional resources.

Comment: Thanks for the copy-resources pointer, that seems to have moved me forward some. I have a couple of follow on questions; 1) I can get the files into my output, but I have specified the output directory as target/project-1.0-SNAPSHOT/sources. That seems unwise, since the directory name will change from time to time as releases are made. How do I specify the "current building directory" as a variable? also, 2) is maven-war-plugin part of this solution, or an alternative?
Thanks again!

Comment: 2. is a different option, but should avoid the ugliness of copying explicitly to the target directory.

Comment: Ah, got it. It's working with ugliness, but I'll take another look at 2) since it looks like if I can make sense of it, then I'll have a cleaner solution. Appreciate your help, many thanks.

Comment: 2. Works great for me. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Drew, that got me where I needed to go. Bottom line, I added the sample pom fragment from the link you gave for copy-resources to my pom.xml with the following changes:

<outputDirectory>target/${project.name}-${project.version}/sources ...

<directory>src/main/java ...

I copied this from the link you gave, then edited the  element to point at src/main/java, which picked up my files, and the outputDirectory to the aggregate target/${project.name}-${project.version}/sources . I found that ${project.name} mapped to the project, and the version came from ${project.version}, which seemed to resolve the last little bits of issue.

Thanks again.
Toby